# escaped_fragment request doesnt parse php?

Tags: php, parsing, hashbang

so recently ive rebuilt my site following Google's AJAX Crawling methods.

Everything works fine and an `?_escaped_fragment_=` request works fine but i've noticed any php on the page is not parsed and is commented out like so: `<!--?php echo $myvar ?-->`

Does anyone know why this may be happening?? here is some PHP from my index:

```
$fragment = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];
    $file = '' . (isset($fragment) && $fragment != '' && $fragment != '/' ? preg_replace('/\//', '', $fragment) : 'home') . '.html';
    $re = '/(^<[^>]*>)|(\n|\r\n|\t|\s{2,4})*/';

    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    if ($handle != false) {
        $content = preg_replace($re, '', fread($handle, filesize($file)));
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        $content = 'Page not found!';
        header(php_sapi_name() == 'cgi' ? 'Status: 404' : 'HTTP/1.1 404');
    }
```

I noticed a regexp in there. Maybe that has something to do with it? I cant fully understand whats going on here, im no expert.
Dont exactly want to put my site back up if this is gonna stay like this..

Please lend me a hand here

Comment: The regex simply changes a blank fragment into `home`, or escapes any `/` into `\/` in non-blank fragments. It would NOT create an html comment as you're seeing. Nothing in that code snippet creates HTML comments, in fact.

Comment: @Marc B thanks for the info, im not at all handy with regex, i forgot to mention that the HTML files contain PHP but my htaccess has a handler for this, maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: No idea. Might be a security module of some sort, or some other parser thinking the PHP is invalid xml (`<?` is used by xml as well) and trying to "fix" it.

Comment: @Marc B aah! Thanks for that, the actual code was developed for xml so it may be that, i'll try it out and report back

Comment: @Marc B no unfortunatly that doesnt help.. something is happening

Comment: Is the change happening as you publish your site to an external hosting service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was solved by creating a PHP if else statement.